# emit keydown.enter event in child

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to emit a "keydown.enter" form parent component in to child component. I am unable to do it. Please guide me on how I can achieve this.

ParentComponent.html

```
<form [formGroup]='parentForm'>
  <div>
    <input type='search' placeholder="search (keydown.enter)="search($event)">
  </div>
  <app-child (keydown.enter)="search()" [childForm]="parentForm.controls.childForm"> 
  </app-child>
</form>
```

ChildComponent.ts

```
@Output() keydown.enter = new EventEmitter(); // keydown.enter does not work

ngAfterViewInit() {
  // something like.. 
  this.keydown.enter.emit({ 
    // keydown.enter does not work
  });
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to do the opposite. You are trying to catch the keydown event of the child in the parent component. Am I right?

Comment: No, I am trying to catch keydown event of the parent component in child component.

Answer (score 2):

**keydown.enter** is not a valid identifier in typescript or javascript

I have replicated ur code

```
//child component
  @HostListener('document:keydown.enter', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.keydownEnter.emit(event)
    
}

  @Output() keydownEnter = new EventEmitter();





//parent component html

<app-child (keydownEnter)="Search()" ></app-child>






 // parent component 
Search() {
  console.log("event")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you need an @Input in your ChildComponent not an @Output. The ChildComponent is listening to some kind of event, not emitting it.

Then I'd do something like this

ParentComponent.html

```
<form [formGroup]='parentForm'>
  <div>
    <input type="search" placeholder="search" (keydown.enter)="_search$.next($event.target.value)">
  </div>
  <app-child [search]="search$" [childForm]="parentForm.controls.childForm"> 
  </app-child>
</form>
```

ParentComponent.ts

```js
public _search$ = new Subject();
public search$ = this._search$.asObservable();
```

ChildComponent.ts

```js
@Input() search: Observable<string>;


ngOnInit() {
  this.search.subscribe(val => 
  // Do Something with searched input
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some Subject and Symbol as a trigger for updating child component

Parent component:

```
class ParentComponent {
  reloadSubject: BehaviorSubject<symbol> = new BehaviorSubject(Symbol(''));

  search() {
    // your code...
    this.reloadSubject.next(Symbol(''));
  }  
}

<form [formGroup]='parentForm'>
   <div>
      <input type='search' placeholder="search" (keydown.enter)="search($event)">
   </div>
   <app-child [reload] = "reloadSubject | async" [childForm] = "parentForm.controls.childForm"> </app-child>
</form>
```

Child component:

```
@Input() set reload(data: symbol) {
  // here you can run some logic for your child component...
}
```